# How to calculate current time since an SKShader was added to a sprite?

Tags: opengl-es, sprite-kit, glsl, shader

The `u_time` variable in shaders tells you the current time. However, if you reuse a shader (as is [best practice according to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshader): "If multiple sprites need the same behavior, create one shader object and associate it with every sprite[…]"), then `u_time` continues counting from the *first* time it's added to a scene. This makes it difficult to use shaders to produce certain types of effects, such as a simple fade from black to white, as below:

```
void main() {
    float duration = 3.0; // seconds
    float progress = u_time / duration;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(progress, progress, progress, 1.0);
}
```

This shader works as intended the first time it's added to a sprite, as `u_time` starts from zero. However, subsequent reuses of the same shader code start with a non-zero `u_time`. And so, subsequent shaders will start fully white and not render the intended black-to-white fade. This seems to very much limit the possible utility of `SKShader`.

Answer (score 4):

I've found an approach that works, but I'm dissatisfied with it. Possibly even dissatisfied enough that I'd rather recompile the shader each time I add it to the scene.

The general idea is to provide a sprite-specific attribute to the shader which tracks when the shader was added to that sprite. To calculate that, track the very first time the shader was ever added to the scene (which is when we know `u_time` should be zero). Then each time we add the shader to a sprite, take the difference between that very first timestamp and the current time. Provide that difference as an attribute `a_startTime` (which corresponds to when we would have liked `u_time`, or something else in its place, to be zero). Then in the shader, `a_startTime - u_time` is the current timestamp, starting from zero, since the shader was added.

Here's what the entire implementation looks like. Track the first time you attach the shader to a sprite in a global variable like so:

```m
static dispatch_once_t firstStartToken;
static float firstStart;

dispatch_once(&firstStartToken, ^{
    firstStart = (float)CACurrentMediaTime();
});
```

This `firstStart` variable marks the timestamp when the shader's `u_time` uniform is zero.

We also have to declare an attribute `a_startTime` for the `SKShader` instance to have a place to fill in the current sprite's start time:

```m
[shader setAttributes:@[
    [SKAttribute attributeWithName:@"a_startTime" type:SKAttributeTypeFloat]]];
```

Then, each time you add the shader to an `SKSpriteNode`, set the sprite's attribute `a_startTime` to be the current time *relative to the initial `u_time`*.

```m
float startTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - firstStart;
[sprite setValue:[SKAttributeValue valueWithFloat:startTime]
    forAttributeNamed:@"a_startTime"];
```

Finally, have the shader implementation use `a_startTime`:

```m
void main() {
    float duration = 3.0; // seconds
    float progress = (u_time - a_startTime) / duration;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(progress, progress, progress, 1.0);
}
```

This approach seems to work. Each time I add this shader to a sprite it fades from black to white as desired.

However, I'm concerned about its fragility in relying on some implementation details of `SKShader`. The first is that `u_time` will always continue ticking up: if in future versions of iOS there are circumstances when it pauses, or is reset to zero, then this code will break by providing negative or huge values for the current time. The other potential breakage is that I assume `u_time` counts up using `CACurrentMediaTime()`, which only *appears* to correspond directly to what's in `u_time`; there may be situations, like a daylight saving time cutover, where these timers will diverge.

Comment: Using breakpoints seems to be one way to get the timers to desync. Not by itself a showstopper, but it does give even more of a sense that this approach is fragile.

Answer (score 2):

First add an attribute to the shader, then use custom action to pass that time inside.  It will reset from zero every time you run it.

```
let a = SKAttribute(name: "TimeElsp", type: .float)
skshader.attributes = [a]

let shaderAction = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: 0.3) { (node, time) in
        let s = node as? SKSpriteNode
        print("time = \(time)")
        s?.setValue(SKAttributeValue(float: Float(time)), forAttribute: "TimeElsp")

    }
```

Comment: Or you can use a u_time % x to find the remainder every time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an experienced programmer, but I think I found a better solution for this problem: 
Simply pass the elapsed time since the app started to the shader as a uniform, and subtract it from u_time.

To do this, I save the `CACurrentMediaTime()` right when the app starts:

`let startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()`

This way I can tell my shader how much time has passed:

```
let shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "shader.fsh")
let currentTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
let timeSinceAppStart = Float(currentTime - startTime)
shader.uniforms = [SKUniform(name: "time", float: timeSinceAppStart)]
```

Then I can simply do this in my shader code:

```
float appTime = u_time - time;
```

Now *appTime* is counting just like *u_time*, but starting from 0.

Comment: Thank you Mario. That's pretty much exactly the answer I described though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set an `a_elapsed_time` SKAttribute on the shader and send it to the node in an `update(_:)` method, for example in the [`SKScene.update(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1519802-update). Something like this:

```swift
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var node = SKSpriteNode()
    var lastUpdateTime: TimeInterval = 0
    var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "Shader.fsh")
        shader.attributes = [
            SKAttribute(name: "a_elapsed_time", type: .float),
        ]
        node.shader = shader
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if (lastUpdateTime == 0) {
            lastUpdateTime = currentTime
        }
        let dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
        elapsedTime += dt
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime

        node.setValue(SKAttributeValue(float: Float(elapsedTime)), forAttribute: "a_elapsed_time")
    }
}
```

```c
void main() {
    float duration = 3.0;
    float progress = a_elapsed_time / duration; // use 'a_elapsed_time' instead of 'u_time'

    gl_FragColor = vec4(progress, progress, progress, 1.0);
}
```

Depending on the game structure, this can be very easy to implement. Using a [`GKState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkstate/), for example.

This method will be consistent with any future implementation changes and with the pause state of the game.

Or you can use an [`SKAction.customAction(withDuration:actionBlock:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417745-customaction) like suggested by @mskw [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59902169/1104534).